How to set the GST_BUFFER_FLAG_NON_DROPPABLE flag on I-frames in GStreamer H.264 video streaming?
When streaming H.264 video using GStreamer with the rtpulpfecenc element, I would like to set the GST_BUFFER_FLAG_NON_DROPPABLE flag only on the I-frames (key frames) of the GstBuffer. Can you please guide me on how to properly insert this into the pipeline?
I want to ensure that the I-frames are marked as non-droppable, so they are prioritized during transmission and protected by the FEC (Forward Error Correction) provided by rtpulpfecenc.
Any code snippets or examples demonstrating the proper way to set this flag on I-frames within the GStreamer pipeline would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!
example sender command:
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! x264enc ! video/x-h264, profile=baseline ! rtph264pay pt=96 ! rtpulpfecenc percentage=100 pt=122 ! udpsink port=8888
